# Generate a vector: when values in one vector match another vector, input the value of another vector at the same position in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I am trying to create a new vector in a dataframe in R, based on vectors in another dataframe.

I have a dataframe which contains outlet numbers. And another dataframe (a concordance table) which shows which outlet name corresponds with which outlet number. Using the concordance table, I want to find the names of the outlets for each relevant outlet number in my first dataframe, and put these into the first dataframe as a new vector.

Here is an example of my data

```
outlet <- rep(1:26)
outletname <- letters[1:26]
concordance <- data.frame(outlet, outletname)
df1 <- data.frame(outlet)
```

What I want to do, is say to R when `df1$outlet == concordance$outlet` return the value for `concordance$outletname` at the same position within the vector of `concordance$outlet`

Does anyone know how to do this? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It's just a merge I think - `merge(df1, concordance, by="outlet")`

Comment: Thanks very much. It definitely is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example data `df1$outlet` is already equal to `concordance$outlet` at all points. I assume you want something that works even when that's not true, so let's scramble the data first to check that what we do works in all cases:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 = df1[sample(1:nrow(df1)), , drop = FALSE]
```

Then you can merge in the outlet names:

```
df1 = merge(df1, concordance, by="outlet", sort = FALSE)
```